# ImageIO error HTML not displaying images taken from iPhone in web view

Tags: iphone, html, webview, javax.imageio

In my app i am taking images and saving in documents directory.
when displaying in tableView, images are displaying fine but while loading in web view with same images with locally created HTML from xml and xslt it is showing following error

```
<Error>: ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk
```

working fine on simulator when captured images from photo library.
Can some one help me out.
code for xslt for images is

```
<xsl:for-each select="PrecisionVestor/PhotoSection/Photo">
<div style="width:46%; height:180px; float:left; margin-top:10px; margin-left:2%; margin-right:2%;">
<div class="caption_pic" >
<img style="background-size:cover;">
<xsl:attribute name="src">
<xsl:value-of select="PhotoPath" />
</xsl:attribute>
</img>
</div>
<div class="caption_txt" ><xsl:value-of select="Note" /></div>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Post your code for review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have solved this problem.
Instead of saving images while capturing in png format saved them in jpeg format.